# Can I delete the history and keep the sha of recent git commits?

Tags: git

I have a 4 year old repository which realistically doesn't need more than a year of history.

Basically assume my tree's hashes look like `I` and I want, logically, `II`:

```
I)   0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-a-b-c-d-e-f
II)  a-b-c-d-e-f
```

I've seen advice to truncate history a bit like this:

```
git log --after="2018-12-28" --until="2018-12-31" #finding a good quiet period
git checkout --orphan trunc 4bf6824d4
git commit -m "Truncated history to 2019-12-29: a low activity point"
git fetch --all
git rebase --onto trunc 4bf6824d4 upstream/master
#OR
git cherry-pick 4bf6824d4..upstream/master
```

Then remove the upstream master and replace it with trunc renamed to master. Or force a push.
I ran this scenario and the outcome is `III` instead, but I thought I could roughly at least get `IV`.

```
III) g-h-i-j-k-l (h-l are b'-c'-d'-e'-f')
IV)  g-b-c-d-e-f (like editing the parent of b only)
```

Is this impossible because you can't edit any given SHA's lineage?
How can I make it that everyone's in-progress work will likely merge with the replacement branch… are they all going to have to pull the new branch and rebase a range of their own work onto it?
Also, why did rebasing give me a few points where conflicts occurred and I had to merge with `theirs`?

Comment: Were there any merge commits in `h-l`? If yes, rebasing deleted them and you had to solve the conflicts again. Using `theirs` thus sounds wrong. The SHA hash for a commit is calculated including the files and and the parent commit. If you change the parent of `b` from `a` to `g`, the hash of `b` will change — which is why you got `h` instead of `b`.

Comment: As for your colleagues, have a look at this: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_recovering_from_upstream_rebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The [Object Database](https://git-scm.com/docs/user-manual#the-object-database) section of the [Git User Manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/user-manual) explains.

> In fact, all the information needed to represent the history of a project is stored in objects with such names. In each case the name is calculated by taking the SHA-1 hash of the contents of the object. The SHA-1 hash is a cryptographic hash function …
>
> - A “commit” object ties such directory hierarchies together into a directed acyclic graph of revisions —​ each commit contains the object name of exactly one tree designating the directory hierarchy at the time of the commit. In addition, a commit refers to “parent” commit objects that describe the history of how we arrived at that directory hierarchy.

By changing your `a` commit to a root commit, *i.e.*, changing its parent from `9` to null, you necessarily and unavoidably change its hash or object name, which is a function of the commit’s tree, parent or parents, author, committer, and commit message as defined in the [Commit Object](https://git-scm.com/docs/user-manual#commit-object) section of the Git User Manual.

> As you can see, a commit is defined by:
>
> - a tree: The SHA-1 name of a tree object (as defined below), representing the contents of a directory at a certain point in time.
> - parent(s): The SHA-1 name(s) of some number of commits which represent the immediately previous step(s) in the history of the
>     project. The example above has one parent; merge commits may have more
>     than one. A commit with no parents is called a "root" commit, and
>     represents the initial revision of a project. Each project must have
>     at least one root. A project can also have multiple roots, though that
>     isn’t common (or necessarily a good idea).
> - an author: The name of the person responsible for this change, together with its date.
> - a committer: The name of the person who actually created the commit, with the date it was done. This may be different from the author, for
>     example, if the author was someone who wrote a patch and emailed it to
>     the person who used it to create the commit.
> - a comment describing this commit.

Changing `a` to `a'` knocks over the first domino in a chain that forces `b'`, `c'`, `d'`, `e'`, and `f'` because the parent of each changed.